# Import variable from another script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a personal assisstant. I would like to import a variable from another file. Despite there are many questions releated to my problem I can't find an answer that works.

- Example of how the system works
- Script with a function always listening
- I say a word (ex: 'hello') and it runs another function
- I say sthg (ex: 'time in Barcelona')
- It takes the last part (ex: 'Barcelona') and stores it into a variable (ex: loc)
- It runs another script (ex: time.py)

main.py

```
def googlecheck():
    attempts = 0
    # Importar fitxers - config.py = variables globals
    import config
    # Salutació de l'assistent a partir de la funció
    hi = ['Gerard']
    tts('Hola ' + random.choice(hi))
    while True:
        print(1)
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as msg:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(msg)
            audio = r.listen(msg, phrase_time_limit=5)
        try:
            # Inicia la variable global mainvr
            config.init()
            config.mainvr = r.recognize_google(audio, language='es-ES')
            print(config.mainvr)
        except:
            # Si no es detecta cap paraula, suma 1, si s'arriba a 3, (3 vegades error), torna a la función principal.
            attempts += 1
            if attempts >= 3:
                activ()
                break
            continue

        hora = ['hora', 'en']
        exit = ['salir', 'adiós', 'hasta pronto', 'vete', 'cállate']
        if all(a in config.mainvr for a in hora):
            loc = config.mainvr[8:]
            print(loc)
            import hora
        if any(b in config.mainvr for b in exit):
            break
        else:
            # Si no es detecta cap paraula, suma 1, si s'arriba a 3, (3 vegades error), torna a la función principal.
            attempts += 1
            if attempts >= 3:
                activ()
                break
```

PD: There is another part of code that calls this function when I say 'hello'.

time.py

```
def f():
    from main.googlecheck() import loc
    print(loc)

f()
```

At this point, I would like to get the loc variable in the time.py file. If I have two files with a variable already defined (ex: loc = Valls), and no functions, it works.

I am using the import method to do it, I think it might be something I do wrong as the method should be working despite the variable is not strictly defined. Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
from main.googlecheck() import loc
```

… doesn't make much sense.

You're calling `main.googlecheck()`—which will work if you've previously done an `import main`—and then trying to import the result as a module—which will not. The result of that function isn't a module. In fact, because you don't `return` anything anywhere, the result is `None`. So, you're trying to `import` something from `None`.

The only thing you can `import` is modules, or globals (constants, variables, functions, classes, other modules, whatever, as long as they're global names) from modules.

(Plus the syntax is invalid, but that isn't as important. If you were trying to do something meaningful and just getting a bracket in the wrong place, fixing the syntax would be the key, but if you're trying to do something that doesn't make sense in the first place, it doesn't really matter how you try to write it.)

---

What I think you want to do here is change `googlecheck to`return loc` at the end, and then change this line of code to:

```
loc = main.googlecheck()
```

That won't fix *all* of your problems, of course, just this one. For just one example: That `loc` doesn't get set unless the `if all(a in config.mainvr for a in hora)` happens at least once. So if, say, `any(b in config.mainvr for b in exit)` is true before that's ever true, you will get an `UnboundLocalError` when you `break` out of the loop and then try to `return loc` without ever creating it.

Also, your code is doing some strange things that may or may not be wrong. For example, you `import hora` in the middle of a loop. I'm not sure what you expect that to do. What it will actually do is run the top-level code in `hora` the first time, and run nothing every subsequent time. And, either way, it will create a local variable named `hora` that holds the module object. I'm not sure why you'd want to do any part of that.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Now, I will try to fix this issue and will report it back to you. As for the import hora, I meant to open another file (hora.py) that would run when I said 'time in X', I am not sure if it is the best way to do it, but I have done some research and it seems to be what I need, if it isn't I would appreciate if you could lighten the path to the answer.

Comment: I have been looking to the answer more carefully and I think that you might not understand how I am trying to work out the solution to this project (or maybe I don't). You have told me to use `loc = main.googlecheck()`. I guess that this code should be placed in the time.py file not in the main.py, but I don't want the program to run like this. The code I have addead (main.py) will check the user answer (with voice recognition). If the Key words are in a list then it should run some code, what I want to do here is run another script for every answer, time, weather, add task...

Comment: So the reason why I added the `import hora` under the `if all(a in config.mainvr for a in hora):` is because I want to run this script only when the user answer has the key words `time` and `in`. Maybe I have misunderstood the way import works. Then, I wanted to import the user answer into a file because I want to check the city to search for the time in there. When I do `loc = config.mainvr[8:]`,  I just want to know the city, not the whole answer. I am sorry if this seems weird to you but I am not a professional developper and I have to learn everything on my own so sometimes it is hard.

Comment: I have doing some more research and I have found this: 'from module import * is invalid inside function definitions.'. The loc variable is inside a function so it won't work.